# Shipping cost estimation displays a wrong element

Tags: shipping, magento2.2.6

[image]

My magento version is 2.2.6.
I'm using a custom shipping module.

During the estimation of the shipping costs, it shows this weird links. The estimated price is ok but the display is not Ok.

In the checkout page, it looks better:
[image]

Where could it be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post your shipping method code for displaying?

Comment: Have you developed the module or did any customization to third-party module?

Comment: https://www.fancourier.ro/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Magento-2.x.zip

Comment: Module is a third-party module done for Magento.